# Using a RegExp to reformat d/m/yy to yyyy-mm-dd strings in VBA

Tags: regex, vba

In [access](/questions/tagged/access) , Australian dates in `SQL` statements are delimited and formatted as *#d/m/yyyy#*.  For example:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mydate BETWEEN #2/1/2001# AND #4/3/2001# AND more...
```

I need to grab this `SQL` statement and massage it so I can present it to `SQLite` as:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mydate BETWEEN '2001-01-02' AND '2001-03-04' AND more...
```

The task, then, is to convert `#xd/xm/yyyy#` to `'yyyy-mm-dd'`.  The "Hello, World!" of regex examples.

Using [vba](/questions/tagged/vba)[regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp) with `.Global = TRUE`, I'm able to replace the delimiters and re-order the elements in one step:

```
vOldPattern = "#([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{4})#"
vNewPattern = "'$3-$2-$1'"
```

This gives the following intermediate result:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mydate BETWEEN '2001-1-2' AND '2001-3-4' AND more...
```

I thought I could pad all the single digits with a single pass:

```
vOldPattern = "-(\d[-'])"
vNewPattern = "-0$1"
```

but this approach padded only the first (month) digit.  I gave up and ran through two passes, matching first on 
`"-(\d-)"`

and then on 
`"-(\d')"`

So, three passes to alter the format and tweak the content.  Surely there's a single search/replace command for this task.  Can somebody volunteer a more elegant solution?

And, since I have to compile and export the runtime, I guess I can't use late binding but instead need to load the reference to the MS VBScript Regular Expressions.  I'm developing in Win7/32, but the app needs to be backwards-compatible (compatible?) with WinXP.  Which version (1.0 or 5.5) of the VBScript RegEx library should I load?

Cheers!

Comment: I'm not familiar with VBA's regex pattern. Can you use `vOldPattern="-(\d\b)", vNewPattern="-0$1"` in your first (single pass) attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead to get around padding only the first zero - which I think occurred for you as the last `-` is consumed in testing for a non-digit for your second `-`

So it can be reduced to two patterns as below

I don't think it can be done in a single shot but I'd like to see it.

I used
`2/12/2001`
rather than
`2/1/2001`
to prove the replacement handles mixed strings

```
Sub Test()
Dim strIn As String
Dim objRegex As Object
strIn = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mydate BETWEEN #2/12/2001# AND #4/3/2001# AND more"
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
.Global = True
.Pattern = "#([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{4})#"
strIn = .Replace(strIn, ("$3-$2-$1"))
.Pattern = "(-)(\d)(?=[^\d])"
strIn = .Replace(strIn, "$10$2")
MsgBox strIn
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Brett.  The positive look-ahead works swell to reduce the process from three to two passes.  I simplified the second pass just slightly.  I can't post it here so I'll answer my own question, but give you all the glory.  Cheers!

Comment: +1 for `regex`, they make VBA a good sport among those super duper cousins of it like c# .net... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could perform this entire task with the [`Format()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx).

If not, you could use Format() to put the leading zeros in.  Something like this:

```
vNewPattern = _
    "'" & Format("$3","00") & "-" & Format("$2","00") & "-" & Format("$1","00")
```

Admittedly, it is not elegant.  However, it is clear, and it should be just as efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are not necessary. Just use the format() function:

```
Dim myDate As Date
myDate = #4/3/2001#
Debug.Print Format(myDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Comment: I think you missed that the question is parsing and formatting a string - it isn't taking a date as an input.

Comment: Ooops, yes - I've just re-read the question. I thought he needs to take the resulting dates and massage them. Sorry for that.

Comment: However - just re-re-reading it: his date values (#...#) must come from somewhere - they won't be hardcoded, will they? So he may well be able to use format in his re-formatted statement.

Comment: The WHERE clause is assigned directly from a recordset filter, so I have no control over the date formatting.  I'm trying to tweak any embedded dates without deconstructing (or even inspecting) the entire filter string.  So, in this case, I think regex is the way to go.  But thanks anyway.  I'd forgotten about Format(), and may have use for it elsewhere in my code.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Brett's answer above is elegant enough for me.  I simplified the syntax of the second pass just slightly, but left Brett's solution as comments.

```
Sub Test()
Dim strIn As String
Dim objRegex As Object
strIn = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mydate BETWEEN #2/12/2001# AND #4/3/2001# AND more"
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
.Global = True
.Pattern = "#([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{4})#"
strIn = .Replace(strIn, ("'$3-$2-$1'"))
'.Pattern = "(-)(\d)(?=[^\d])"
'strIn = .Replace(strIn, "$10$2")
.Pattern = "-(\d)(?=[^\d])"
strIn = .Replace(strIn, "-0$1")
MsgBox strIn
End With
End Sub
```

brettdj and I would both love to see a single-pass solution to this problem.  I bet we could do it in good ol' perl!

The second part of my original question was which version (1.0 or 5.5) of the VBScript RegEx library I should register so that I could generate a runtime application.  I pulled the trigger and selected just the 5.5. version (has it REALLY been around since 1999?).  The application compiles successfully.  If it doesn't run as a stand-alone, I'll let you know.